# Evaluating a list-like string into a string

Tags: python, string, list

Say that I have a string that looks something like this:

```py
    x = "['345565', '1234213', '12313523', '1232346345', '1223123']"
```

Is there a built-in method in Python or numpy that I can use to automatically convert this into a list?  I'm familiar with the `eval()` method and what I'm looking for is something of the same idea.

Comment: At the moment, you don't have a string, you have a syntax error. Please make sure your example is a [example].

Comment: You need to change the left and right single-quotes to double.  Then use `eval`.  As posted, this isn't legal Python.

Comment: @Prune Please don't suggest `evil` when `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads` can both handle it safely :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it ok ?

```py
import ast
x = "['345565', '1234213', '12313523', '1232346345', '1223123']"
print(ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python built in library ast.
[ast docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = "['345565', '1234213', '12313523', '1232346345', '1223123']"
>>> x_array = ast.literal_eval(x)
>>> print(x_array)
['345565', '1234213', '12313523', '1232346345', '1223123']
>>> type(x_array)
<class 'list'>
>>> x_array
['345565', '1234213', '12313523', '1232346345', '1223123']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `json` module, but you'll have to swop the single quotes for double quotes to make it legit json:

```
import json
x = "['345565', '1234213', '12313523', '1232346345', '1223123']"
json.loads(x.replace("'", '"'))
```